# C++ EventHandler class, invoking & arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, event-handling, callback

This is my `EventHandler` class, which is extremely simple and can be used on lambdas and similar:

```
template<typename Signature, typename...Ax>
class Event
{
private:
    typedef std::function<Signature(Ax...)> Function;
    Function _func;

public:

    void CallFunc(Ax... ax)
    {
        if (_func)
        {
            (_func)(ax...);
        }
    }

    void operator+=(Function func)
    {
        _func = func;
    }

};
```

I'm looking to find improvements as it's basically as simple as it gets.

Example:

```
Event<void, int> myEvent;
myEvent += [](int arg) { printf("%i", arg); };

myEvent.CallFunc(15);
```

Would print out **15**.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like that you use `operator +=` to set the function. `+=` suggests that I can append a bunch of functions and they all get called when the event happens, which is not the case. `myEvent.setFunction([](int){});` would be better.

It would make sense to take advantage of move semantics. The lambda that gets passed into `myEvent` is moved into `func` and then copied into `_func`, when 2 moves would have been enough:

```
void operator+=(Function func)
{
    _func = std::move(func);
}
```

Better yet: Make it a template and perfect forward the argument to have only 1 move:

```
template<class Fun>
void operator+=(Fun &&func)
{
    _func = std::forward<Fun>(func);
}
```

You get somewhat worse error messages but most likely better performance.

Same goes for `CallFunc`, it should take a variadic template argument that gets perfect forwarded into the call for efficiency.

Speaking of efficiency, the flexibility of `std::function` comes at a price. It is known at compile time what types `func` can be, so `_func` should be exactly the same type without type erasure and virtual function calls. You can make that work with a `template <class Fun> Event<Fun> make_event(Fun &&fun)` style function to get the type of the function and create an `Event` with the appropriate template parameters, but you lose the ability to specify the function later.

There are extra parenthesis in the call `(_func)(ax...);`. Maybe it is a style thing, but I would write `_func(ax...);` instead.

Oh, and `printf` is not very C++y, but it was just an example.

Comment: Its based on C#'s event system, well sort of atleast. The += is often used to assign the handler to a function.

However I will try and do less moves and use perfect forwarding! :)

Also because you have a nice point about the += operator making you think that you can append more than one function to the event, thats actually a good idea, as I can easily add -=! :D

Answer (score 3):

**`operator +=` to assign a new handler to the event?** It seems quite unconventional to me. `+=` gives the impression that you're appending something, not the case there. Why not simply an assignment?

Furthermore, why bother defining a class at all? You could use `std::function` directly, combined with a template alias:

```
template<class RetType, class... Args>
using Event = std::function<RetType(Args...)>;
```

Then use it much the same way, but with the proper function call operator instead:

```
// define
Event<void> event = []() {
    std::cout << "Hey!\n";
};

// call the handler
event();
```

Comment: Its based on C#'s event system, well sort of atleast. The += is often used to assign the handler to a function. 
Since I still want to use the += operator because it is really the general operator for assigning a function to an event handler! :D

However Instead of using the function CallFunc imma use the () operator. :)